# How do you create a simple and cheap tension alarm?

Tags: sensor, piezo-buzzer

**Background**

I'm creating some party games and someone had the idea to place yarn or string in a hallway, similar to laser grid, that people would have to navigate without touching.

**Problem**

So I was wondering if it is possible to use something like https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10293 to create a buzzing sound (or a light) when a person bumped into one of the "lasers".

I've seen different tutorials, but most involve things like arduino boards or batteries, both of which are impractical for this scenario. So, is their away to hook up a string to a piezoelectric sensor that buzzes if the string gets bumped?

Comment: Well I think what you have there is a speaker, so you can't hook it up simply without giving it a frequency. Why not use a buzzer instead so when some trips the wire, it pulls the circuit closed and let the battery power the buzzer?

Comment: @Bradman175 What kind of buzzer could I use that would just accept DC power to turn it on.

Comment: @qw3n any number of self oscillating buzzers. Top of my head, five bucks at radio shack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A piece of non conductive material and a clothes pin. Cover both sides of the clothes pin in foil and connect to your circuit. Tie the non conductive material (plastic, paper, cardboard) to the string and put it in the clothespin as to break the circuit. Place it so that the slightest bump names the wire fall out. Instant trip wire.

https://youtu.be/wB6BEHAUZow